# bootstrap: form-control size doesnt change based on parent div col size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use increase the size of my text box but changing col-md-* value doesn't seem to affect the child input form-control textbox.

Example:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            Name:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a name ..." class="form-control" required="required" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In above code the text input size doesn't increase to what I think should be larger if I used col-md-8. The text box size is same whether I use col-md-4 or col-md-6 also. Is it because form-control class in bootstrap defines a size? If so how can this be fixed?

Comment: `.form-control` sets the width to 100%.  What are you expecting that's different from this? http://jsbin.com/yobo/1/edit

Comment: When I run, I don't get the width as big as in your example. I always see the input size probably equal to col-md-4 size.

Comment: Not much we can do to help.  Put your code in exactly as you've provided and it works.  Maybe you're overriding `.form-control` in your CSS?

Comment: :-( , I searched through the entire project but don't see overriding the default .form-control class where the width is indeed set to 100%. Not sure what is going on

Answer (score 0):

Try this its work for me

```
<div class="row">
        <form id="myForm">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                Name:
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input name="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter a name ..." class="form-control" required="required" />
            </div>
        </form> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I have other form drop downs, text boxes etc inside the form element as well. I just put an example with one textbox.